# Decode 2 50 17. 0339 03 28 92046796

Tags: cipher

After completing the UKMT Maths challenge, you receive a certificate of completion and a key fob.

The key fob always contains a puzzle on it. [See this site for previous years](http://www.arbelos.co.uk/keyfobs.html). This year it was a cipher:

```
IMOK 2017

Decode:

2 50 17. 
0339 03 28 
92046796
```

There is also the hint:

> 'It may help to think about some of the obvious letters. For example, there are not many choices for “2‘.'

Can anyone decode this?

Comment: What are we looking for?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Puzzling. Please see [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/25966). Thanks!

Comment: what cipher is it using?

Comment: This is from the UKMT 2017 key fob. I have one myself (I recommend you include an image, or I can in a bit)

Comment: I have edited this puzzle to expand, and to give more information

Comment: @JonMarkPerry That is the whole point...

Answer (score 5):

The code appears to follow a substitution cipher, where each numeric digit corresponds to a letter. Four of them are immediately easy to find.

> The first line tells us that:
>
>  2=I, 0=M, 1=O, 7=K

Replace them in the message, and then solve for the remaining six digits. In this example you can solve the lines in order.

> 1. `I 5M OK.` looks like "I AM OK." So 5=A.
>  2. `M339 M3 I8` looks like "MEET ME IN". So 3=E, 8=N, 9=T.
>  3. `TIM46KT6` can't be much other than "TIMBUKTU". So 4=B and 6=U.

The message becomes:

> I AM OK.
>  MEET ME IN
>  TIMBUKTU

Comment: Ah thats what I says. I've been pondering this a while now

Comment: But what does it mean?!

Comment: @Forklift That you need to book a flight to Timbuktu soon... ;c)